# How to add jars into the classpath and get effected without restarting the hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, jar, classpath

I wrote some `mapreduce` jobs that reference a few external jars.
so I added them into the CLASSPATH of the "running" cluster in order to run jobs.

Once I tried to run them, I got class not found exceptions.
I Googled for ways to fix it and I found that I needed to restart the cluster for applying
the changed CLASSPATH, and it actually worked.

Oh, yuck!
Should I really need to restart a cluster every time I add new jars into the CLASSPATH?
I don't think that it makes sense.

Does anyone know how to apply the changes without restarting them?

---

I think I need to add some detail to beg your advice.

I wrote a custom `hbase` filter class and packed it in a jar.
And I wrote a `mapreduce` job that uses the custom filter class and packed it in an another jar.
Because the filter class jar wasn't in the class path of my "running" cluster, I added it.
But I couldn't succeed to run the job until I restarted the cluster.

Of course, I know I could packed the filter class and the job in a single jar together.
But I didn't mean it. 
And I'm curious I should restart the cluster again if I need to add new external jars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Cloudera [article](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) for including 3rd party libraries required for the Job. Option (1) and (2) don't require the Cluster to be restarted.

Answer (score -1):

You could have such a system that dynamically resolve class names to an interface type to process your data.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I think I should have wrote details.